# How to call a function by using a number n

Tags: dart

I would like to have a list of functions and call one of them by using a number n to call the nth function of the list.

I thought that the best way to do this would be by using a map, but I can immediately spot some problems that I don't know how to solve in this example:

```
import 'dart:math';

void functionOne(x) => print("the randomly generated number is $x");
void functionTwo(x) => print("the inverse of the randomly generated number is ${1/x}");

var example = {0:functionOne(), 1:functionTwo()};

var intValue = Random().nextInt(2);
var biggerIntValue = Random().nextInt(100) + 1;

void main() {
  example[0](biggerIntValue);
}
```

I would like to be able to pass parameters into said function and be able to access the functions by using a number. I know that I could make one giant function and use if statements to do certain actions, but I was wondering if there was any predetermined syntax that would look better than this:

```
import 'dart:math';

void largeFunction(funcNumber, x) {
  if (funcNumber == 0) {functionOne(x);}
  if (funcNumber == 1) {functionTwo(x);}
}

void functionOne(x) => print("the randomly generated number is $x");
void functionTwo(x) => print("the inverse of the randomly generated number is ${1/x}");

var intValue = Random().nextInt(2);
var biggerIntValue = Random().nextInt(100) + 1;

void main() {
  largeFunction(intValue, biggerIntValue);
}
```

Thanks for reading my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem with the map is that you call the function expressions. Try:

```dart
var example = {0:functionOne, 1:functionTwo};
```

The next problem will be that

```dart
example[0](biggerIntValue);
```

complains that `example[0]` is nullable.
I'd change that to:

```dart
example[0]?.call(biggerIntValue);
```

so that it only calls something if the integer is a key in the map.

Comment: And a `Map` with contiguous, integer keys starting from 0 also might as well be a `List`, which would avoid the need for null-checks.